# Php-ajax отправка и принятие массива чекбоксов

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Есть много чекбоксов типа `type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check[]\"` с разными  `value`

Отправляю через форму

Если дописать в форме `action=\"edit.php\"`, то успешно передается массив чекбоксов, который в `php` я перебираю/принимаю так: `foreach($_POST['check'] as $id) {...}`

А если не дописывать `action` и передавать без перезагрузки страницы, таким образом:

```
document.getElementById('del-form').onsubmit = function(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "edit.php", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send("check[]=" + this.check[].value);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert('Информация о доме добавлена');
        }
    }
    http.onerror = function() {
        alert('Извините, данные не были добавлены');
    }
    return false;
}
```

То массив не передается (если передавать какое-нибудь поле, то оно успешно передается таким способом)

Помогите, пожалуйста, если можно наглядно. Я перелопатил кучу сайтов и боюсь, что ответ без примера не особо поможет. Я понял `this.check[].value` это не правильно, но как правильно не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На чистом JS:
разместите этот код перед закрывающим тегом body (в самом конце страницы)

```
var my_form = document.getElementById('del-form');
my_form.onsubmit = function(){

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var str_req = "";

for (var i=0; i<my_form.elements.length; i++) {
    if (my_form.elements[i].name == "check[]" && my_form.elements[i].checked) {
        str_req +="&check[]="+my_form.elements[i].value
    }
}
http.open("POST", "edit.php", true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.send(str_req);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert('Информация о доме добавлена');
    }
}
http.onerror = function() {
    alert('Извините, данные не были добавлены');
}
return false;
}
```

С использованием jquery:

```
$(function() {
$('#del-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var fdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.post("edit.php", fdata, function(data){ alert('Информация о доме добавлена');},"json");
    return false
});
});
```

Comment: (выбрал чистый js вариант)а как на стороне php принять str_req и работать с каждым значением? делаю так не получается foreach($_POST as $id){ 
print $id;
}

Comment: разобрался, нужно было не мудрить и принимать, как раньше

   foreach($_POST['check'] as $id) {...}

ОГРОМНОЕ СПС!

Answer (score 1):

Вашу проблему элементарно решить, исполузуя jQuery:

```
var query = $('input[type="checkbox"]').serialize();
```

Таким образом в переменной query окажутся значения всех чекбоксов.

По поводу action формы. В атрибуте action указывается тот скрипт, которому будет отправлен запрос GET или POST. Если атрибут action отсутствует или пустой, запрос отправляется на текущую страницу. Таким образом, не указав в action edit.php, данные формы отправляются скрипту вашей текущей страницы.

Также советую использовать плагин Firebug для Firefox'a или Developer tools Сhrome'a, для проверки вашего javascript'a и отслеживания ajax-запросов.